# R - setting NA to zero in an aggregate function

Tags: r, missing-data, var, aggregation

In R, I'm trying to run the following code to find the variance of several rows in a data frame. The variance is correctly calculated when there is more than 1 case, but obviously produces `NA` when there is only one case of ID1&ID2.

```
collated <- aggregate(.~ID1+ID2, interactionData, FUN=var, na.rm=TRUE)
```

In the above code, is there a way to force R to set to `0` rather than `NA`

(I know that I could run a line of code afterwards along the lines of `collated[is.na(collated)] <- 0`. However, I'm just wondering if there is a ay to do this all within the `aggregate` function.

Comment: You can try `aggregate(.~ID1+ID2, interactionData, FUN=function(x) if(length(x)==1) 0 else var(x, na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: Any example input so we can confirm ideas ? (I think the `na.action` parameter of aggregate could be a way to tackle it)

Comment: Honestly, I think replacing the `NA`s with 0's in a separate line afterwards is what I'd do. Easy to understand and readable.

Comment: @joran Thanks! I had already tried replying NAs with 0, which worked absolutely fine (and yes it is extremely readable). I was just trying to extend my knowledge by seeing if others could point out alternate options.

Comment: @Tensibai - I had spent a bit of time trying to work out if I could use na.action=etc but couldn't find anything that would set to zero.

Comment: @akrun that worked thank you! I hadn't thought about using an if(x, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create an `if/else` condition based on the `length` to output those with `length` as 1 to 0 or `else` get the `var` of the variable.

```
aggregate(.~ID1+ID2, interactionData, FUN=function(x)
         if(length(x)==1) 0 else var(x, na.rm=TRUE))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
interactionData <- data.frame(ID1= rep(1:4, each=3), 
  ID2= sample(LETTERS[1:5], 12, replace=TRUE), value= rnorm(12))
```

Comment: As mentioned above, this worked perfectly. I had not considered the if(x...) option as I had been stuck thinking along the na.action= route. Thank you so much @akrun